# Pegando Variaveis da URL em Uma Pagina, e usando em outra

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, variáveis

tenho um link na qual recebo os parametros na url completamente, no caso aponta pra um HTML onde tenho meus inputs, e recebo a URL com os parametros, 
o que preciso e pegar as variaveis dessa URL e usar em outra pagina quando der um submit em um form...

o LINK

https://www.lascivacam.com.br/pagseguro/index.php?email=artnilipservicos@gmail.com&token=A391905466FD2ED45ECD0&receiverEmail=aervisadacoasds@gmail.com&currency=BRL&itemId1=1&itemDescription1=30%20Chips&itemAmount1=30.00&usuario=LascivaCam&itemQuantity1=1&reference=7|1|30&senderEmail=contato@lascivacam.com.br

preciso salvar as variáveis e guardar nas variaves e poder usar normalmente nas outras paginas... mas não estou conseguindo...

Posso usar php ou jquery mas n faço ideia porque e mais de 1 variavel que vou precisar carregar...

So pra esclarecer :

MEU INDEX e html PURO ONDE TEM UM INPUT, nesse input quando preencho os dados posso escolher qual tipo de pagamento realizo, e nele há um php para cada um dos tipos de pagamento, por isso a precisão de pegar as variaveis acima para poder utilizar no preenchimento de valores e outros dados q vao ficar no bd e na hora do pagamento...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma sessão para armazenar esses valores.

Na sessão você pode armazenar valores que "persistem" entre uma página e outra pois são mantidas nas requisições HTML para o seu servidor.

Como no código abaixo:

Página que recebe as variáveis:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['nome_var'] = $_GET['var'];
```

Página que usa as variáveis `session_start();` acesse os valores pelo `$_SESSION['nome_var']` setado.

Answer (score 1):

Seria o ideal fazer um único script PHP.

Você pode passar um input com o id da forma de pagamento selecionada para o script PHP, e depois usar uma declaração switch.

Exemplo.

```
switch ($_POST['tipo_pagamento']) {
case 0:
    echo "sua logica de programação";
    break;
case 1:
    echo "sua logica de programação";
    break;
case 2:
    echo "sua logica de programação";
    break;
}
```

Comment: rsrs, no caso já foi feito já, porque foi pela URl, mas ta tudo ok, meu problema agora e outro preciso fazer uma verificação do BD onde confere o status do pagamento se for diferente pega o usuario que pagou e ID da transação para conferir e o ID e a quantidade de chips q ele comprou e atualiza em outra tabela esses dados...